# Could not find RubyGem mloughran-api_cache (>= 0)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I'm getting this error trying to do a rake db:migrate -->
Could not find RubyGem mloughran-api_cache (>= 0)

Not I know that's a gem missing, But for some reason I can't find the whereabout of that gem. It's no the gem called api_cache. Or at least if it is, the system does not recognized that it is installed.

Any help would be really appreciated.
Thanx.
Yohann T

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I show as the gem:

```
➜ gem list -r mloughran-api_cache

*** REMOTE GEMS ***

mloughran-api_cache (0.2.0)
```

with the following sources:

```
➜ gem sources
*** CURRENT SOURCES ***

http://gems.rubyforge.org
http://gems.github.com
```

Comment: Good answer, 

The source for that gem is the github one.
Add that source using:
 gem install -r mloughran-api_cache